# Как сохранить данные парсинга в csv?

Tags: python-3.x

Написал тут код на питоне который парсит сайты но проблема в том что я не могу сохранить полученный данные(в основном это текст) в csv файл. Нужна ваша помощь. 
[image: скриншот]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

page =requests.get('https://indir.gamer.com.tr/strateji-oyunlari/252-ancestors-legacy-indir.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
f=csv.writer(open("muhy.csv","w"))
f.writerow([])
metin_list=soup.find(class_="full-right1-2")
ls=soup.find(class_="dlevideoplayer")
ls.decompose()
es=soup.find(class_="highslide")
es.decompose()
print(metin_list)
f.writerow.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю что ты хочешь сделать. Тебе нужен чистый текст из класса full-right1-2 который будет записан в файл формата csv?
Если да то можно как то так. (не самый лучший код)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = "https://indir.gamer.com.tr/strateji-oyunlari/252-ancestors-
legacy-indir.html"

page =requests.get(url)
metin_list=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
metin_list.append(soup.find(class_="full-right1-2").text)

with open('data.csv','a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(metin_list)
```